# For an RLC circuit with square wave input, why isn't the output a square wave?

Tags: passive-networks, remote-control, circuits

In an RLC series circuit if we provide a square wave signal as input, why is the output signal at R not also a square wave? Is it a sinusoidal wave?

[image]

I am running the simulation on Multisim.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy's answer can be summaries like this: 1. A square wave consists of the adding together of a sine wave plus all it's odd harmonics. (f + f/3 + f/5 + ....). 2. The RLC circuit acts as a frequency dependant filter 3. The RLC filter removes various amounts of the fundamental and harmonics. 4. What is left is some combination of various amounts of the original frequency and harmonics. 5. The result is closer to a sine wave than the input but is not a perfect sine wave as it is still a mix of some of the fundamental frequency and a variable amount of various harmonics.

Comment: Why would you expect what comes out of a filter to generally be the same as what you put into the filter? If you put a mix of water and sand through a filter, you don't expect a mix of water and sand coming out of it.

Answer (score 5):

(Nearly) any periodic signal can be decomposed into a sum of sinusoidal signals with multiple frequencies of the base frequency. Square waves contain only frequencies with odd multiples of the base frequency. For a more detailed description you may visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave .
The capacitor and the inductor in your circuit constitute a resonant circuit which is obviously tuned to the ninefold base frequency (the relevant data is not completely readable in your screen shot). At this frequency the LC combination has zero resistance. Hence this signal will not be attenuated and that is what you basically see on your oscilloscope. For all other frequencies the absolute resistance is greater zero and the LC combination together with the resistor R constitute a voltage divider which leads to a reduction of the corresponding input voltage at the oscilloscope.

Comment: It's not nearly any--it's literally any.

Comment: Hearth, you are right for periodic functions sufficiently well behaved. But give me the Fourier transform of a function which is zero at each rational point in time and one at each irrational point in time.

Comment: I need more simple answer because I didn’t study signals analysis

Comment: I'm afraid there is no much simpler answer.

Comment: @Elec1 I wouldn't generally consider something that can't physically be used as a signal to be a "signal".

Answer (score 2):

> why the output signal at R is not also square ?

A square wave consists of the superposition of a sine wave and all it's odd harmonics. The RLC circuit acts like a filter, and attenuates different frequencies by different amounts. Thus, the square wave loses some the amplitudes of some of its components, and it becomes distorted.

> is it sinusoidal wave

No. For it to be sinusoidal, you would need to filter out all frequencies except one. A simple RLC circuit cannot do that. However, in some cases an RLC circuit (if it has high enough "Q") can come close, and the result looks close to a sinusoid.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified summary of "Math Keeps Me Busy"'s answer:

1. A square wave consists of the adding together of a sine wave plus all it's odd harmonics.
   (f + f/3 + f/5 + ....).
2. The RLC circuit acts as a frequency dependant filter
3. The RLC filter removes various amounts of the fundamental and harmonics.
4. What is left is some combination of various amounts of the original frequency and harmonics.
5. The result is closer to a sine wave than the input but is not a perfect sine wave as it is still a mix of some of the fundamental frequency and a variable amount of various harmonics.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first the transfer function of your circuit is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{out}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}+\text{sL}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}=\frac{\text{RsC}}{\text{RsC}+\text{sLsC}+1}=\frac{\text{CRs}}{\text{CLs}^2+\text{CRs}+1}\tag1$$

We, know that:

$$\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1}{1-\exp\left(-\text{Ts}\right)}\int_0^\text{T}\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}\exp\left(-\text{s}t\right)\space\text{d}t=$$
$$\frac{1}{1-\exp\left(-\text{Ts}\right)}\cdot\left\{\int_0^\tau\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}\exp\left(-\text{s}t\right)\space\text{d}t+\int_\tau^\text{T}0\cdot\exp\left(-\text{s}t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}=$$
$$\frac{1}{1-\exp\left(-\text{Ts}\right)}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}\left(1-\exp\left(-\text{s}\tau\right)\right)}{\text{s}}=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\text{s}\tau\right)}{1-\exp\left(-\text{Ts}\right)}\tag2$$

So, we can see that:

$$\text{v}_\text{out}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\text{s}\tau\right)}{1-\exp\left(-\text{Ts}\right)}\cdot\frac{\text{CRs}}{\text{CLs}^2+\text{CRs}+1}=$$
$$\frac{1-\exp\left(-\text{s}\tau\right)}{1-\exp\left(-\text{Ts}\right)}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}\text{CR}}{\text{CLs}^2+\text{CRs}+1}\tag3$$

Comment: "Whoosh, thonk!"  I think your answer just sailed right past the OP and hit the wall a couple of meters back.  The basic level of the question makes it very unlikely that the asking person has even the slightest idea of how all that math answers the question.  I can follow how you've set up the first equations, though I can't follow the rest of it.  What I do know is that to make sense of that math you have to have some idea of the concepts behind it - which the OP obviously doesn't have.

Comment: I need more simple answer because I didn’t study signals analysis